# How to set images on different screens in bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I want to show 2 images on small screen and 4 images on large screen using bootstrap how will I achieve that .

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
  <img src="">
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
  <img src="">
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
  <img src="">
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
  <img src="">
 </div>
</div>
```

but this code work fine on my laptop screen but when I responsive that page it shows only one image on one row

Comment: Please [refer the the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/#responsive-classes). Use the `xs` breakpoint if you don't want the columns to stack vertically. For example: https://codeply.com/p/v5cZ8KIaBD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hey! I'd advice to read the [Bootstrap layout docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/) for better understanding.


A row contains 12 columns in bootstrap grid. 

 With the prefixes for responsive layout [xs, sm, md, lg, xl]** 
 xs (Extra Small) -> Screens <576px 
 sm (Small) -> Screens ≥ 576px 
 md (Medium) --> Screens ≥ 768px 
 lg (Large) -> Screns ≥ 992px 
 xl (Extra large) -> Screens ≥ 1200px

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  
  <!-- 
  The numbers will specify how you want to control the view on various devices.
  A row = 12 columns
  If you want 2 images to appear on a screen, that would be 12/2 = 6.
  Therefore, the grid number would be 6 (6 + 6 = 12 (A row!))
  
   If you want 3 images to appear on a screen, that would be 12/3 = 4.
  Therefore, the grid number would be 4 (4 + 4 + 4 = 12 (A row!))
  
  If you want 4 images to appear on a screen, that would be 12/4 = 3.
  Therefore, the grid number would be 3 (3 + 3 + 3 = 12 (A row!))
  
  If you want an image to appear on the whole screen, that would be  a full row = 12 (col-{layout_prefix}-12)
  
  The formula is just :
  for items < 4 
  A full row(12)/number of items per screen
  -->
  
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
       <img class="img-fluid"    src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/assets/img/bootstrap-icons.png">
 </div>
 <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
  <img class="img-fluid" src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/assets/img/bootstrap-icons.png">
 </div>
 <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
  <img class="img-fluid" src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/assets/img/bootstrap-icons.png">
 </div>
 <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
  <img class="img-fluid" src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/assets/img/bootstrap-icons.png">
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```